# Tkinter child's window button to change he contents of the list box

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a `toplevel` (child) window with a label and a button. The button command is connected to a function that changes the `child`'s window label text. I got an "undefined name..." for the name of the child window label. I'm new to Python and tkinter and I'm sure this is something very simple. I would appreciate any pointers anyone can give.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Root")

def child(): #Create child window
    child = tk.Toplevel()
    child.geometry("350x350+100+100")
    child.title("Child Window")
    
    lb1 = tk.Label(child, text = "Child Label")
    lb1.pack()
    
    Cbtn = tk.Button(child, text = "Change Child Label text", command = cLabelChange)
    Cbtn.pack()

def cLabelChange():
    lb1.configure(text = "I changed this text") #THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS

btn = tk.Button(root, text = "Open Child.", command = child)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I have looked high and low but nothing. Maybe I am wording the question incorrectly..

Answer (score 0):

> tkinter child window button to change contents of list box

The problem can be fixed.

- Move `cLabelChange()` function inside `child()` function.
- Move `Cbtn` and `pack` of outside `cLabelChange()` function at the
  bottom.

That all.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Root")
root.geometry("300x300")
 

def child(): #Create child window
    child = tk.Toplevel()
    child.title("Child Window")
    child.geometry("350x350+100+100")
         
    lb1 = tk.Label(child, text = "Child Label")
    lb1.pack()
         
    def cLabelChange():
        lb1.configure(text = "I changed this text") #THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
        child.update()

    Cbtn = tk.Button(child, text = "Change Child Label text", command = cLabelChange)
    Cbtn.pack()    

btn = tk.Button(root, text = "Open Child.", command = child)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly. That worked well and was a great teaching lesson for me…where you place your code is important.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an alternative solution to your problem. Pass the `lb1` as an argument to your `labelChange()` function so that label widget will be accessible inside function like the following. To do this obviously you have to use `lambda` function to pass the argument.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Root")

def child(): #Create child window
    child = tk.Toplevel()
    child.geometry("350x350+100+100")
    child.title("Child Window")
    
    lb1 = tk.Label(child, text = "Child Label")
    lb1.pack()
    
    Cbtn = tk.Button(child, text = "Change Child Label text", command = lambda:cLabelChange(lb1))
    Cbtn.pack()

def cLabelChange(lb1):
    lb1.configure(text = "I changed this text") #THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS

btn = tk.Button(root, text = "Open Child.", command = child)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried passing the label name using lambda but I just couldn't get it right and gave up. Thanks, another good lesson learned.